# gcloud appengine-java install on Fedora 28

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-yum) to install the app-engine-java gcloud component on Fedora 28. It appears that it wants JDK 1.7 installed, but Fedora says that JDK 1.8 "obsoletes" 1.7 and won't let me install it next to JDK 1.8. Has anyone else run into this? Is it a bug, or just Fedora being unsupported?

I'm sure there's a binary installer that I could use, but I'd like to use the package if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that worked for me was

```
$dnf download google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java
```

and

```
$rpm -ivh <downloaded-rpm> --nodeps
```